# Nginx with multiple services on same port and domain issue

Tags: linux, nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, web-development-server

**Theory**

i have configured nginx as a reverse proxy to serve multiple services, each on one port.

**example**:  AI service exposed on port 60004:

```
127.0.0.1:6004/predict

127.0.0.1:6004/docs
```

**what i did?**

- i have created a virtual server in "/nginx/sites-available"
  directory and linked an ssl certificate to my domain:

  ```
   server {
   server_name classifier.domain.net;

   include /etc/nginx/default.d/classifier.domain.net/*.conf; #managed by me


   listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/classifier.domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/classifier.domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


   }

        server {

        listen 80;
        server_name classifier.domain.net;
        return 301 https://classifier.domain.net$request_uri;

   }
  ```
- in the above site file, i have included the actual path where i have configured "location" directives that will redirect traffic to the desired ports, instead of adding them in the same file. "just more structured way" then,
- i have configured "location" directive to use the desired proxy_pass as i want:

  **location directives**

  ```
   ## for the first service "train", runs on port:6004

   location  /train {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6004/train;
   }

   location /train/docs {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6004/docs;

   }
  ```

  ### for second service "predict", runs on port:6005

  ```
   location  /predict {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6005/predict;
   }

   location /predict/docs {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6005/docs;

   }
  ```
- first two "locations"  serve the following endpoints:

  127.0.0.1:6004/predict
  127.0.0.1:6004/docs
- second two "locations" serve the following endpoints:

  127.0.0.1:6005/predict

  127.0.0.1:6005/docs

**what was the Problem?**

- in two locations, i can reach "**/train**" & "**/predict**" and no issues,
- **the problem in two locations is**:  "**/docs**" which always returns undesired output: [plz show the screenshot link]
  [undesired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHO5j.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHO5j.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHO5j.png

**what i had tried?**

actually i had tried everything '_' but lastly,
**i changed one location directive to:**

```
## changing first service "train" which runs on port:6004 to be served on "/":
        location  / {
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6004/;
              }
```

### keeping second service "predict" as it was, runs on port:6005

```
        location  /predict {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6005/predict;
        }
        
        location /predict/docs {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6005/docs;
        
        }
```

now i can reach **6004/train** & **6004/docs** & "6005/predict" and  BUT
i **could not** reach "/docs" for other ports like host:6005/docs
so i think that, it was not the proper solution

Comment: Please describe the unexpected output or error you get from the /docs location.

Comment: Could you please share your nginx configuration?

Comment: @Andrea  i have edited the question with a code section that contain site configuration inside "sites-available" folder

Comment: @Bman70 i have edited the question with a screenshot of the output, in the section of "what is the problem",

Comment: So you're saying that `https://my.example.com/train/docs/openapi.json` returns error 404? Are you sure that the application that is listening on port 6004 under pathname `/docs` can actually find `openapi.json` inside `/docs` folder ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV  thanks for ur cooperation, 
/docs is not a folder, actually it's an endpoint, so i should get a response for /docs itself.

i am working on a fastapi project, AI engineer has created an endpoint called "train" for example, this endpoint creates "/docs" by default at the same port, so you can reeach "host:6004/train"  &  "host:6004/docs"
but unfortuatley i can reach /train but no for /docs

Comment: Most probably the issue is not nginX but the AI that is listening on port 6004. On your screenshot it says that `openapi.json` is not found - so it probably does not request (just) the `/docs` endpoint ...

Comment: Hi @IVOGELOV
i have updated my question with more clarification to get the point, but for your doubt, i am agree with u, but i dont know why nginx can not find this file while i can get it through the same endpoint but using public IP instead of ports:
here is a screenshot of the output when i reach endpoint **/docs**   through public ip: 
https://paste.pics/I6DG8
second screenshot for the actual json content when i reach : **host:6004/openapi.json**:  https://paste.pics/I6DAS

Comment: @IVOGELOV  i  think we are about to get the solution.
workaround: why i get "openapi.json not found" despite reaching it through public ip using /docs and /docs should actually display openapi.json content

Comment: @karim please switch the order you're using to set the values as /train will get all the calls to /train and /train/docs, you should put before /train/docs and after /train to route it correctly.

Comment: @Andrea sorry andrea but i did not get the point, are u asking me to change the order of /train/docs to be before /train ??

Comment: @karim yes, exactly

Comment: I believe that you want to map `https://my.example.com/docs/openapi.json` into `internal://127.0.0.1:6004/openapi.json` With your current config the mapping is actually `internal://127.0.0.1:6004/docs/openapi.json` You will have to use a regex location block and capture the path afer `/docs` and then specify that `$1` in the `proxy_pass`

Comment: @IVOGELOV   applying the suggested solution, returns the actual json file content without the style:   here is the applied configs: https://paste.pics/I707D     &&  for the output:  https://paste.pics/I7071

Comment: @IVOGELOV i agree with you that the problem maybe in nginx "location" directive, maybe should arranged in a different way, because when i use location directive with "/"  mapped to port:6004 , i can get /train  &  /docs  with its full style  because of this i think there is no problem in fastapi code itself.

Comment: Don't forget that if you include a trailing slash in the `proxy_pass` directive - it will strip the location prefix, without the trailing slash - it will send the full path to the upstream.

Comment: Yes, sure, that is why whatever the typed alias after the slash, it redirects me to /docs for train service only.